# Using 'self' in an anonymous callback?

Tags: php, anonymous-function

Take a contrived example where I want to call a `protected static` method from another context through a callback function:

```
class Foo {

    protected static function toBeCalled() { }

    public static function bar() {
        functionThatAcceptsACallback(function () {
            self::toBeCalled();
        });
    }

}
```

Is this possible in PHP 5.3? I couldn't find a way to make it work...

Comment: Have you tried passing it like any other outer variable with `use`? `function() use (&self) { ... }` you might need to bind it to another variable rather than using the keyword.

Comment: @Orbling That's the problem, it's a *keyword*, not a variable. If it's used in any form other than `self::methodName` it's recognized as a constant. (Go PHP!（ー＿ー;;）)

Comment: My understanding is that anonymous functions have their own scope and do not have access to anything outside except via use.  However, on the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), it says that from v5.4.0+ `$this` now works within a closure, so perhaps `self` does too on that version.

Comment: In "functionThatAcceptsACallback" do you mean to declare or bind this to anything (function or variable)? Right now this isn't even PHP syntax ... :)

Comment: @Alexander This is perfectly fine PHP syntax, assuming I have declared a `function functionThatAcceptsACallback($callback) { $callback(); }`.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're doing. :P) I was confused thinking you'd go completely OO on my ass. Anyway, found one possible way (answered below), but not sure about state of the resulting static method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[It's not possible](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures/removal-of-this), but it will be in 5.4 along with support for `$this` in a closure.

> Added closure $this support back. (Stas)

[Reference](https://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/trunk/NEWS)

**Edit**

This works in 5.4alpha1.

```
    class A
    {

        private function y()
        {
            print "y".PHP_EOL;
        }

        static private function z()
        {
            print "z".PHP_EOL;
        }

        function x()
        {
            return function() {
                $this->y();
                self::z();
            };
        }

    }

    $class = new A();

    $closure = $class->x();

    $closure();

    /*
    Output:
    y
    z
    */
```

Comment: I knew about `$this`, but it doesn't seem sure that that'll work for `self`. We'll see, I guess.

Comment: @deceze Closures have no understanding of the context of which they are created in. So `self`, `static` and `$this` is meaningless. This "context" awareness is being added to 5.4. While I think it would have been fairly easy to implement `self`, I believe they removed it for consistency (since `$this` support wasn't planned for 5.3).

Comment: If it wasn't such a pain I'd install 5.4 and try it… ;-) Anyway, thanks for confirming that it's not possible as of now.

Comment: Uuuh, nice update. Looks promising! Only three more years now until I can use this in production. ;-D

Comment: @deceze You wish it'd be 3 years. Given all the features they are removing in 5.4, I'm doubting it will ever get adopted by some hosts. I know Rackspace Cloudsites is STILL not offering a 5.3 solution.

Comment: "404 Not Found" for "Reference" link in the answer.